# How can I speed up posting to ServiceBus?

Tags: azureservicebus

The following Azure Function is running on Azure (UK South) and posting messages to a Service Bus that is also in UK South.

This is taking 25 seconds, which means I am getting a rate of approximately 40 messages per second, which is nowhere near enough.

Please note that the actual requirement I have is to send messages sequentially to various queues/topics in order they are found in a database, so I cannot use batch send.

Is there a way to speed this up, as 40 per second is not fast enough?

```cs
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net;
using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
 
namespace Speedtest
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
 
        public Function1(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Function1>();
        }
 
        [Function("Function1")]
        public async Task<HttpResponseData> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req)
        {
            var client = new ServiceBusClient("...omitted...");
 
            var sender = client.CreateSender("customercreated");
 
            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
 
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                var message = new ServiceBusMessage($"Hahaahahaha{i}");
                await sender.SendMessageAsync(message);
            }
 
            sw.Stop();
 
            var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
 
            response.WriteString($"Time taken was {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
 
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came up with was to have a topic named `events-ingestion` and post to that in bulk.

Then I have multiple subscriptions on that topic with filter criteria like `Target = 'customer-created'` with a rule to forward the messages to the `customer-created` topic.

This way I am seeing a massive throughput even from my remote machine.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're creating a new `ServiceBusClient` and `ServiceBusSender` on each call, you're paying the cost of establishing the connection, establishing the link, and authorization each time you send a single message.

We recommend treating the Azure SDK clients as singletons, ideally by taking advantage of the Function host's dependency injection.  This ensures that client lifetime is correctly managed, and disposal takes place.  Examples of registering Service Bus types with DI can be found in [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/overview/azure/messaging.servicebus-readme?view=azure-dotnet#registering-with-aspnet-core-dependency-injection) of the overview and more discussion and examples can be found in the article [Dependency injection with the Azure SDK for .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/azure/sdk/dependency-injection?tabs=web-app-builder).

One thing to be aware of is that there is an idle timeout associated with the clients (default of 60 seconds) and the service (30 minutes at the time this was written).  If your Function is being invoked infrequently, you may need to adjust the [ConnectionIdleTimeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebusclientoptions.connectionidletimeout?view=azure-dotnet#azure-messaging-servicebus-servicebusclientoptions-connectionidletimeout) property on the options passed when creating your `ServiceBusClient`.  The service idle timeout cannot be adjusted; if you're sending less frequently than the service interval, you have no choice but to pay the connection cost.

Comment: I know they are usually singletons, but this is demo code. The slow part of the code is the loop, not the creation. It is the loop itself that takes about 25 seconds to execute.

Comment: The client is lazy.  You won't pay the connection tax until you call `SendMessageAsync` for the first time.   Your first call is likely taking the large majority of your 25 seconds.

Your statement about not being able to use the batch is also strange to me, as the ordering inside a batch is maintained during a send.  Outside of performance, there's no difference between sending message in a batch or 1-by-1, if using the same entity.  Though it is also worth mentioning Service Bus itself does not guarantee ordering outside of using sessions.

Answer (score 0):

> The slow part of the code is the loop, not the creation. It is the loop itself that takes about 25 seconds to execute.

That's expected as the code is sending each message and is awaiting for the operation completion. To speed it up, send each message and keep the reference of the task in a collection, awaiting for completion of all the tasks with `Task.WhenAll`.

Comment: Note: While valid, the trade-off with this approach is that with non-deterministic ordering of messages.  Building a batch and sending as a single call will maintain the order.

Comment: True. But messages order is such a funny business to begin with. Might as well save yourself the pain and account for unordered messaging.

Comment: Agreed.  Just wanted to call attention to it here, since the OP had mentioned ordering was important to them.

Comment: True. Having messages sent in a sequence doesn't guarantee sequential processing. Not to mention that the ask to have sequential sending _and_ high throughput are not going hand in hand. The OP got enough information to decide how to go about the problem. Personally, I would try not to deal with ordered messaging if possible. But when it's necessary, use sessions, not worry about high throughput, and think hard about failures in the processor side. Because that will happen and ASB doesn't have a good story to offer OOTB.